# node_module doesnt syncronize with host

Tags: angular, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to make an Angular application dockerized, but for some reason it doesnt map properly.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /app
# Project and dependencies are here ( package.json, etc. )
COPY .  /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install && npm audit fix #--force #will

# The default port from ng serve (4200)
# and 49153 for Webpack Hot Module Reload
EXPOSE 4200 49153

RUN $(npm bin)/ng serve
```

with my docker-compose.yml

version: '3.5'

services:

```
  my-angular-app:
    container_name: my-angular-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - "80:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
    expose:
      - "4200"
      - "49153"
```

the thing is that ir run

OUTPUT:

```
...
Step 11/11 : RUN $(npm bin)/ng serve
 ---> Running in 8a50b007a0ea
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-03-07T18:45:25.430Z
Hash: 2c3511aa07ccc9ecc246
Time: 6584ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 112 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 241 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 18.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.53 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

but when I try `localhost` doesnt navigate, when I change a file inside the container the modification doesn't appear on the project. And if I change the file on the project the change doesn't show on the container.

Probably is a stuped mistake but I've spend 5 hours and nothing :(

Comment: I can't tell from your question, if you are trying to set up a live development server in a docker container. Or if you are just curious about dockerizing your Angular application. Can you specify what you intend to use the image for in the question? Then perhaps I can help you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to start the Angular server while the image is being built.

The reason that you cannot connect to the Angular live server during the build, is that the build command executes in a context where the container does not have any ports accessible or mapped back to the host. Basically, you are not supposed to interact with the docker process that builds your image. You are supposed to let it build the image and then start the image as a container, in order to interact with it.

If you want to run your angular live development server in an alpine docker container - you need a few things.

1. You need to update your package.json, with a script that will start the live development server without binding it to `localhost``in the docker container.
2. You need to make sure that the `node-sass` module is rebuilt when you start the container - because the native bindings that are built for your hostmachine, are not the ones that work on alpine. (Unless your host operating system is also alpine).
3. You need to update your Dockerfile, installing `python2` and `g++`, these are needed when rebuilding the `node-sass` module.

**Update to package.json:**

Create a new script element `start:docker`, that will install dependencies, rebuild the `node-sass` module and start the live development server, not binding it to the `localhost` loopback device.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:docker": "npm install && npm rebuild node-sass --force && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    ...
```

**Update the Dockerfile:**

Next, the update to the `Dockerfile`. I am going off from your original file here. I removed the bit where you copy the application into the image, and run `npm install`. Instead I am installing `python` and `g++`, in preparation for when the container will rebuild the `node-sass` module on startup.

For a "live development server image" it will not be needed to copy the project into the image when building it. Instead we need to bind it as a volume in the container when we start it. Like you are doing in your docker-compose definition. And then install the dependencies on startup.

And also, I set an `ENTRYPOINT` for the image, it will run the command from the `package.json` scripts section that we just created.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache make git
# Dependencies needed for 'npm rebuild node-sass --force'
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++

# Create app directory and set as working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# The default port from ng serve (4200)
# and 49153 for Webpack Hot Module Reload
EXPOSE 4200 49153

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:docker"]
```

No update is needed to the docker-compose.yml file to make this work. I would mention though, that you do not need to use the `expose`:` for anything. You are already exposing those ports in the Dockerfile.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  my-angular-app:
    container_name: my-angular-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "80:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
```

**Build and run:**

Build the image with this command:

```sh
docker-compose build
```

And then run it with:

```sh
docker-compose up
```

It will take a little while for the live development server to be ready, because it needs to install the dependencies and rebuild the `node-sass` module (which takes a while)

When done, visit http://localhost in a browser, to see it from the host. (You mapped it to host port 80, so no port is needed in the URL)

Comment: Hi, I find that solution as well but I don't want to rebuild node sass is really slow. I though that instead of using `RUN $(npm bin)/ng serve` I could use a CMD but I couldn't make it work with `CMD`

Comment: I will not be possible to access the live development service at build time for the docker image. Remember that it is the image that is being built that that time, it is not being run. Are you trying to use it as a live development server while you are developing? Or for deployment?